# How to architect an application involving heavy Geo-Location computations?

Tags: c#, mongodb, redis, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to create a simple social networking app starting with back-end.

### **App Description**

When a user opens the app *a list of users will be displayed* based on his/her ***Geo-Location, age and gender***.

One a user has been viewed he won't be showed ever again.

### **Technologies**

I am using Azure CosmosDB(MongoDB implementation) and Azure Redis Cache to store the documents.

### **My Approach to deal with the problem**

I save all the user db in cosmosdb. I query for user Ids based on geocoordinate and age and gender preference filters and limit the results by 5000.

I also apply one more filter which is if a user has already been viewed filter. I am maintaining collection where for each user all the user Ids that he viewed will be saved as document.

For the first time I'll get 5000 id's from cosmosdb and put 4950 in redis cache(with an expiry time). Using the remaining 50 ids I'll fetch users from cosmosdb and return it as response to the api call. For subsequent calls I get next 50 ids from redis cache and fetch those users and return as response.

### **Problem I'm facing**

Fetching the 5000 users is a time taking step as it involves geolocation computation and other filtering. I created a sample user database where there are nearly 2 million users in 100 mile radius and I am supposed to get 100,000 users based on my preference i.e, age and gender had I not applied 5000 Limit.
It would take around 25 seconds to do so.

Applying 5000 limit would run the query for 1 - 1.5 seconds only initially. Buy as the users get viewed i.e, when **Not-In ($nin)** filter will exclude those 5000 ids time taken would eventually increase. Time taken to get from cache will be fast  but when the cache gets exhausted or expired and we have to hit cosmos db to query for 5000 more users it would take more time as the users he as already viewed keep increasing.

### **Stats**

Time format is in hrs:min:sec.
It is performed just for performance stats. Actual Api request will provide 50 users each time(most of the time from cache).

**first time**

Time taken to get 5000 matches is  00:00:01.22

Time taken to set Viewed Ids is  00:00:00.06

**second time**

Time taken to get 5000 matches is  00:00:02.49

Time taken to set Viewed Ids is  00:00:00.67

:
:

**Fifteenth time**

Time taken to get 5000 matches is  00:00:23.05

Time taken to set Viewed Ids is  00:00:09.23

**Question**

How can the architecture be improved for better performance ? How apps like Uber, Tinder etc that involve users Geo-Location computations architect their application ? Is there a better way to model the problem or model the data ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please tell us what exactly you want? Not asking an architecture!!

Comment: Since you're already touching redis, have you tried seeing what the redis geo performance is like for your scenario? See `GEOADD` and `GEORADIUS[BYMEMBER][_RO]`

Comment: @MohammadNikravesh - please consider that your response can be interpreted as very aggressive, like you're yelling at someone for asking a question that doesn't fit the guidelines. Considering the negative reputation Stack Overflow gets these days, perhaps choose a different approach?

Comment: @DavidMakogon, Noted, Thanks for your advice

Comment: @Marc Gravell Haven't tried to do any computations on redis side yet. I will try it if it isn't too expensive.

Comment: @MohammadNikravesh I'm asking how the performance can be improved. Do I have to model my data in a different way or use different technology or approach ?

Comment: @THECODER of course, the only way to *find out* how expensive (or not) it is : is to try it with a realistic volume of data. It should take about 10 minutes max to write a script that loads redis with the appropriate test data to try it

Answer (score 1):

2 million users is enough that you need to start having a good indexing strategy for database queries to work.  Geography queries provide a unique indexing problem because they are searches over two related variabled (namely longitude and latitude).

There's a good description of how Microsoft SQL server does their [spacial index over here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-2017), which also nicely summarizes the indexing problem more generally.

While I've not personally used it, CosmoDB seems to now have some support for this too. See [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/documentdb-expanded-geospatial-support-including-automatic-indexing-of-polygons-and-lines/) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/cosmos-db/geospatial).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is slightly rethink your expectations - simply finding the 50 or 5000 (or whatever *n*) nearest items can involve a lengthy search if there are no nearby matches (or even if there are), but if your database is properly indexed, you can search very efficiently within some radius *r* of a point, and then sort those results by distance. If you have or expect to have a large number of coordinates, I would suggest doing that several times, in other words searching for all matches with 100m, sort by distance, and then if you need more, search for all matches within 500m and exclude the ones you've already seen, and so on up to 10km or 25km or whatever your app calls for.

MongoDB has a [quite efficient index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/) available for geospatial coordinates (basically a world map partitioned into B+ trees). [The `'$near'` query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#op._S_near) allows you to specify both minimum and maximum distance, and sorts by distance by default, so it'a very convenient for this kind of tiered, distance based searches. You will have to format your coordinates (both in the DB and in the query) as GeoJSON Point objects if they aren't already, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am already using 2dsphere index . Above mentioned stats include it. Still the performance could be low once he has viewed around 7500 users. It would take 23 seconds to query.

Comment: It sounds like your problem isn't with the location computations, then - it's excluding items based on a growing list of already-viewed IDs. You can, however, use location/distance to better partition the search space instead, letting the spatial index do more of the work for you, instead of doing a (probably linear) search of 5000*n IDs.